# Ошибка преобразования типа IPoint в JSON

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, postgis

В таблице базы данных PostgreSQL есть столбец (nodeCoordinates) где хранятся координаты (тип geography).
Данный столбец связан с моделью в приложении ASP.NET Core MVC:

```
[Column("nodeCoordinates", TypeName = "geography (point)")]
public IPoint NodeCoordinates { get; set; }
```

При запросе с помощью EF Core данные загружаются без проблем:

```
Node node = await _context.Node
.Select(n => new Node
{
     IdNode = n.IdNode,
     NodeCoordinates = n.NodeCoordinates
})
.FirstOrDefaultAsync(n => n.IdNode == id);
```

То есть в поле NodeCoordinates переменной node есть координаты:
[image: IPoint]

Но при возврате Json:

```
return Json(node);
```

Возникает ошибка: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: end of data after property value in object at line 1 column 215 of the JSON data

Необработанные данные выглядят так:
{"idNode":695,
"nameNode":null,
"idTypeNode":null,
"idStation":0,
"barCodeNode":null,
"nodeCoordinates":{"coordinateSequence":{"dimension":3,"ordinates":7,"count":1},"coordinates":[{"x":65.29806667,"y":55.4389,"z":"NaN"

То есть нет закрывающихся скобок.
Почему так происходит? Какой тип нужно использовать, чтобы возвращать Json с координатами?

Выяснилось, что так происходит из-за циклической ссылки. Ошибка: Self referencing loop detected for property 'CoordinateValue' with type 'GeoAPI.Geometries.Coordinate'

Данные которые приходят из БД:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема решается игнорированием циклических ссылок при сериализации:

```
            string nodeJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(node,
            new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
            });
```

Но непонятно почему так происходит.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. У вас есть класс и вы не можете его сериализовать? Или у вас есть строка и мы не можете ее десериализовать? И причем тут базы данных, зачем они в вопросе?

Comment: Есть класс и не получается его сериализовать. Возникает ошибка: Self referencing loop detected for property 'CoordinateValue' with type 'GeoAPI.Geometries.Coordinate'. То есть циклическая ссылка. Я уже разобрался, что если в настройках сериализации включить игнорирование таких случаев, то все будет работать. Но почему возникает эта циклическая ссылка? А базы данных при том, что ошибка возникает именно с данными типа geography.

Comment: Может потому, что node может содержать ссылки на другие  ноды, то есть, может содержать ссылку на себя?

Comment: Нет. Так происходит с любым классом, в котором есть свойство типа IPoint.

Comment: то есть у вас циклическая ссылка где то в IPoint, но вы нам этот тип не показываете?

Comment: public interface IPoint : IGeometry, ICloneable, IComparable, IComparable<IGeometry>, IPuntal
    {
        double X { get; set; }
        double Y { get; set; }
        double Z { get; set; }
        double M { get; set; }
        ICoordinateSequence CoordinateSequence { get; }
    }

Comment: Во первых, добавляйте код в вопрос, в комментариях его читать невозможно. Во вторых, Вы показываете интерфейс, но т вы же сериализуете класс, у класса могут быть дополнительные поля. В третьих, что вот это такое? `ICoordinateSequence`? Нет ли там ссылок на другие точки?

Comment: Я сериализую класс Node, в котором есть свойство типа IPoint. Такой тип создается автоматически при создании моделей из существующей базы данных с помощью entity framework core. Почему тип IPoint содержит  'ICoordinateSequence' не знаю. Мне как раз и нужно получить всего лишь две координаты, а в итоге, когда я получаю данные из базы, свойство NodeCoordinates (тип IPoint) содержит эти координаты в нескольких местах плюс возникает циклическая ссылка.

Comment: ну я, например, не имею понятия, что это за интерфейс такой `IPoint`, но вот если немного [погуглить](https://nettopologysuite.github.io/html/interface_geo_a_p_i_1_1_geometries_1_1_i_point.html), то будет видно, что внутри `IPoint` есть ссылки на другие `IPoint`. То есть я могу предположить, что в каком то месте какой то `IPoint` содержит ссылк на себя, вот у вас и возникает циклическая ссылка.